# Ошибка: fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 140.82.121.4]: errno=Unknown error

Tags: git, git-clone, git-remote

Случилось всё неожиданно, не смог сделать `git push` в свой удалённый репозиторий на GitHub. Позднее обнаружилось, что не работают все команды для работы с удалёнными репозиториями: `git clone`, `git fetch`. Постоянно процесс завершается `Unknown error` "Неизвестной ошибкой".

```
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.121.4]: errno=Unknown error
```

Пробовал несколько способов решения с [похожего вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72486457/fatal-unable-to-connect-to-github-com-github-com0-140-82-121-4-errno-unkno), что получилось:

[image: Пример использования и ошибки]

Мой global `.gitconfig` файл:
[image: gitconfig файл]

Клонирование через VPN так же не принесло никаких результатов

Comment: Я бы начал с `ping github.com`

Comment: И, кстати, протокол git на гитхабе давно отключили

Comment: Умно конечно, но и сайт у меня спокойно грузиться и ping всё выдаёт:
https://imgur.com/a/6AhUn7p

Comment: "протокол git на гитхабе давно отключили". Ок тогда бы `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://` заработал...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема кроется видимо в конфликте двух записей:

```
[url "git://github.com/"]
    pushInsteadOf = https://github.com/
[url "https://github.com/"]
    pushInsteadOf = git://github.com/
```

Стоит заменить данные строчки через `git config --global -e` на:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    pushInsteadOf = git://github.com/
    pushInsteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Тогда авторизация и клонирование снова заработают.